# How to find the Nash equilibrium or subgame perfect equilibirum in a sequential game with imperfect information?

Tags: game-theory

I have a problem with the sequential game with random event at the event tree. The model of the game as follows:

- Player = $\{A,B\}$
- Pure strategy of player $A: A1, A2, A3$
- For each strategy of player $A$, we have some chances, which is presented by the probability as in game tree.
- Pure strategy of player $B$: for type $1$, strategies of $B$ is $B_{11}$ and $B_{12}$. For type $1$, strategies of $B$ is $B_{21}$ and $B_{22}$. For type $3$, strategies of $B$ is $B_{41}$ and $B_{42}$. And for type $4$, strategies of $B$ is $B_{41}, B_{42}$ and $B_{43}$.

The game tree is as follow.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzdN8FPtLFScZU0wY2ROZzgzd3c/view?usp=sharing]

Sorry that I am the newbie, so I do not have enough reputations to post a figure.

The question is that:

1. Find the subgame perfect equilibirum of the game above?
2. Find a pure and a mixed Nash equilibrium points.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The second "for type 1" is presumably meant to read "for type 2"?

Comment: What does "B43r" represent in the middle of the diagram?

Comment: And how are the "types" determined?

Comment: Hi, there are an error in the figure. instead of "B43r", it must be B43. I will upload new figure now.
For the "types", the probability of each type is a function of the strategy of player A. Example: if A plays any strategy, there are 4 cases will be happened: T1, T2, T3 and T4. However, the probability of each types is depended on the strategy of A.

Comment: I removed the tags [tag:combinatorial-game-theory] and [tag:algorithmic-game-theory] -- if you disagree, please explain the rationale for applying them.

Comment: The linked game tree doesn't appear to have payoffs. It will be rather difficult to find a solution (by which I suppose you mean Nash equilibrium) without payoffs.

Comment: I have updated the game tree with the payoffs. Thank for your comments.

Comment: So I gather the uppermost numbers in the diagram (e.g. $1/2$, $1/6$, $1/4$, $1/12$) are the probabilities for the types?

Comment: Yes. They are the probabilities for the types.

Comment: So player A moves, then "nature" moves to determine the type, and then player B moves, knowing both player A's move and the type? No, that would be a bit boring. So player B knows the type, but doesn't know player A's move?

Comment: That's right. Player B only knows the type, but doesn't know player A's move.

Comment: Please put an actual picture in the question, not just a link. Also, why do the players have the same names as the strategies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Théophile pointed out, the strategy names overlap the player names, which invites confusion, so I'll call player $A$'s strategies $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ instead.

Assuming $B$'s decisions to be maximally favourable for $A$ in case $A$ plays $A_2$ yields a maximum expected payoff of

$$
\frac15\cdot22+\frac17\cdot10+\frac14\cdot17+\frac{57}{140}\cdot15=\frac{1133}{70}\approx16.2
$$

for $A$, whereas assuming $B$'s decisions to be maximally adverse to $A$ in case $A$ plays $A_3$ yields a minimum expected payoff of

$$
\frac18\cdot13+\frac14\cdot13+\frac1{16}\cdot9+\frac9{16}\cdot20=\frac{267}{16}\approx16.7
$$

for $A$. The payoff of $A_1$ for $A$ cannot exceed $16$. Thus both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are dominated by $A_3$. It follows that $A$ plays $A_3$, and $B$ plays the corresponding optimal strategies, $B_{11}$, $B_{22}$, $B_{32}$ and $B_{42}$.

The corresponding payoffs are

$$
\frac18\cdot19+\frac14\cdot13+\frac1{16}\cdot9+\frac9{16}\cdot23=19.125
$$

for $A$ and

$$
\frac18\cdot18+\frac14\cdot22+\frac1{16}\cdot18+\frac9{16}\cdot23=21.8125
$$

for $B$.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have an other question: How to find the mixed strategy for this game?

Comment: @Duc-TuyenTa: I don't know what you mean by "the mixed strategy for this game". All other strategies, including mixed strategies, are dominated by the one I described.

Comment: Yes, your answer is true in case that B's decisions to be maximally favourable for A. What the problem if A want to maximize it's payoff when B want to minimize A's payoff? Example: A is an attacker and B is a defender in a security game.

Comment: @Duc-TuyenTa: That's a misunderstanding of my answer. I showed that the expected payoff for $A$ from playing $A_3$ assuming maximally *adverse* decisions by $B$ is higher than the expected payoff for $A$ from playing $A_1$ or $A_2$ under maximally *favourable* decisions by $B$. Thus I made no assumptions about $B$ being favourable to $A$, but rather showed that, irrespective of $B$'s decisions, the expected payoff of $A_3$ is always higher than that of $A_1$ and $A_2$, i.e. $A_3$ strongly dominates $A_1$ and $A_2$, without any assumptions about $B$ (not even that $B$ maximizes $B$'s payoff).

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. You are right. However, your answer seems to only true for this case. It because that I randomly generated the payoff of players. Now, assume that the expected payoff for A from playing A3 assuming maximally adverse decisions by B is smaller than the expected payoff for A from playing A1 or A2 under maximally favourable decisions by B. How to find the NE point of the game?

Comment: @Duc-Tuyen Ta: There's an entire theory for that. The basic idea is that each player must be indifferent with respect to all strategies for which she has non-zero probability. Look up "principle of indifference". I liked the fact that this particular case could be dealt with by a simpler argument; I won't work out an entire mixed equilibrium for you in another case; there's enough on the Web (including this site) to get you going on that. If you encounter any problems, you can ask more specific questions about those.